# Grub multi OS boot for a tablet (with only two "keys")

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, dual-boot, grub, tablet

I am trying to install Linux on a Windows tablet, and my problem is the choice of OS at the grub menu.

The tablet has the power button (keycode 124), volume up (123), down (122)
and "desktop switch" (or whatever it is called), which doesn't seem to provoke a key press event according to xev.

One way of doing it would be to use the volume buttons as arrow keys, and the power button as "enter key".  But would this be "safe"?  I mean, does the grub interpret the signal before the hardware turns it off?  Or inversely, would there be no way to turn off the computer without booting an OS once grub menu appears?

So if the first way is not safe, I am left with only two keys, which means that, as I will need the enter key, I will have only one arrow key.  So would there be a way to write a grub menu so that by pressing down arrow key at the bottom entry, one can go back to the top entry?